# Where can I get English or Kannada translation of Khandanatraya of Shri Madhwacharya?

Tags: vedanta, resource, dvaita, madhvacharya

If you have online links of one or more of Khandanatraya Granthams of Shri Madhwacharya with Kannada or English translation, please share it.

Khandanatraya:
1. Mayavada khandana
2. Upadhi khandana
3. Prapancha Mithyathavnumana khandana

If you have one or more of links for these granthams with translation please share it.

Comment: Useful link: http://www.tatvavada.org/eng/works/dp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find English translations of all these three works. However, I could find Kannada translation and unabridged translation of one or more works.

- **Mayavada Khandanam**

  [**Srimadhvyasa.wordpress.com**](https://srimadhvyasa.wordpress.com) contains details about all the works of Sri Madhvacharya. Mayavada Khandanam is present in verses with [Sanskrit](https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/mayavadhakhandanam14082012.pdf) and [Kannada](https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/mayavadhakhandanam14082012.pdf) versions with verses on their website. But English translation is missing.
- **Upadhi Khandanam**

  Upadhi Khandanam is a short work of 16 verses followed by mangala charanas dedicated to Lord Vishnu. There is an abridged translation on English on [Atmashrama.org](http://www.atmashrama.org/index.php?option=com_guru&view=gurutasks&catid=6&module=29-overview&cid=48-upadhi-khandana&tmpl=component&Itemid=0) explaining the gist of acharya's work. **Copyright - Atmashrama.org**

  Upadhi Khandanam in [Sanskrit](https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/s-05-sanskrit-upadhikhandana-28082013.pdf) and [Kannada](https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/upadhikhandana12082012.pdf) (PDF format).
- **Prapancha mithyatva anumana Khandanam**

  Sri Jayatirtha also known as Tikacharya wrote commentary on this work. The verses in [Kannada](https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/07-kan-prapanchamithyathwanumanakhandan-teeka231120141.pdf) and [Sanskrit](https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/07-san-prapanchamithyathwanumanakhandan-teeka23112014.pdf) are present on above website mentioned in downloadable pdf format.  Dr.G M Jayateertha wrote a Kannada translation for this work.

  [Prapancha mithyatva anumana Khandana pdf](https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/prapanchmk-jayateerthadr.pdf) by Dr. G M Jayateertha.

In addition to these, Dr. P Vinayacharya has translated *Śrī Madhvācārya's Mithyātva-anumāna-khaṇḍanam* into English as a part of *Three Refutations series*. It is available for purchase on the internet.

Comment: Since the answer is incomplete without giving all the works in Kannada or Sanskrit, it is better to wait till the bounty period is over.

Answer (score 0):

Not the translation but here is a english description of the text and the arguments:

https://www.atmashrama.org/index.php?option=com_guru&view=gurutasks&catid=6&module=29-overview&cid=46-mayavada-khandana&tmpl=component&Itemid=0

If you know Kannada, here is the lecture by Sri Bannanje Govindacharya:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGKZCZu3vtM